# nested ng-repeat index not working || nested ng-click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

if we create two or three comment with multiple replies to them the "helpful" link is causing problem when clicked it perform ng-click operation on the index with same number thus showing all the text with same index. how to resolve this nesting so that when a link is clicked only the respective text is shown

http://plnkr.co/edit/XS4Nro3sdIWMnopdgDYG?p=preview

the ng-click and ng-show operation are working through myDiscuss controller

```js
var app = angular.module("myDiscuss", []);
app.controller("TabController", function($scope) {

  $scope.subTab = null;
  
  $scope.subLike=null;



  
  $scope.selectSubLike = function (setTab) {
      $scope.subLike=setTab;
  }
 
  $scope.selectSubTab = function(setTab){
    $scope.subTab = setTab;
  };
 
  $scope.isSelectedSub = function(checkTab){
    return $scope.subTab === checkTab;
  };

  $scope.isSelectedSubLike = function(checkTab){
    return $scope.subLike===checkTab;
  };

});
```

For html file look in the plunker link.

Helpful and Reply link are in the reply-link.html file

Comment: So you want to create a reply inside of reply? Or do you mean when clicking helpful from reply its not going to a right place?

Comment: yes it is not going to a right place for some helpful links
for example : if we click helpful then it is showing all the text with the same index

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/PQ36lMXR1YOs8DP7WXMk?p=preview

What I did is added `helpful: 0` to both comment and reply objects. Also added `<p ng-if="object.helpful">{{ object.helpful }} </p>` to comment-section.html and reply-box.html

Then when clicking on the helpful added a new function called `increaseHelpful(object)` where you increase the helpful variable by one on each click. Of course you need to make it that one user can only click it once but just for example :)

Comment: function name is addHelpful or increaseHelpful as addHelpful function is visible to me

Comment: sorry yes I mean increaseHelpful

Comment: Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: yeah something like this

Answer (score 2):

Get the `index1` also in so you can get the reply box where you click the reply button. Use selectSubTab(index, index1) and then have two variables in  `$scope.subTab` to check what is selected.

Edited from Konkko's plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/lbn57aPTJQpgzMaQPW6t?p=preview

reply-box.html

```
<div  id ="wrapper">
  <form ng-submit="replysubmit()" ng-controller="BlockController">
    <div class="clearfix" ng-if="isSelectedSub(index)">

      <input type="textarea" tabindex="0"
      style="overflow: auto; max-height: 350px; margin-top:1px;" class ="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-11" ng-model="reply.comment"
      name="reply.comment" placeholder="Write a Reply" />
    </div>
    <blockquote  ng-repeat="(index1,object) in replybox">
      <h4>Name</h4>
      <p>
        {{object.comment}} {{index1+1}}
      </p>
      <p ng-if="object.helpful">{{ object.helpful }} </p>
      <ul reply-links></ul>
      <div class="clearfix" ng-if="isSelectedSub(index, index1)">

        <input type="textarea" tabindex="0"
        style="overflow: auto; max-height: 350px; margin-top:1px;" class ="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-11" ng-model="reply.comment"
        name="reply.comment" placeholder="test" />
      </div>
    </blockquote>
  </form>
</div>
```

reply-links.html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li>
      <a href ng-click="increaseHelpful(object)" class="glyphicon ">Helpful</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href ng-click="selectSubTab(index, index1)" class="glyphicon" >Reply</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$scope.subTab = {first: null, second: null};

$scope.selectSubTab = function(setTab, setTab1){
    console.log(setTab);console.log(setTab1);
    $scope.subTab = {first: setTab, second: setTab1};
  };

$scope.isSelectedSub = function(checkTab, checkTab1){
    return $scope.subTab.first === checkTab && $scope.subTab.second === checkTab1;
  };
```

Comment: what is the use ng-init="reply.reply=object" ??

Comment: Oh sorry I left that there. First I thought of making an object inside the reply which create and object inside the object that would allow you to iterate so it would make a tree of replies if needed.